# Get NodeIP or HostIP from inside the pod for the same node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I've a scenario where I want to fetch the node's IP address from inside a pod which is hosted on that same node (daemonset pod). As, I want to put a check something like - if the **pod-A** already exists on the same node(identify using that node's IP address) then wait for it to terminate otherwise create the **pod-A** again. While trying to implement the same in K8s go-client, I'm unable to find a way getting the node's IP from inside the pod on which that pod is currently scheduled. The best I've come across is this method: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.20.4/pkg/util/node/node.go#L149 but the problem being it requires to pass node name as well along with it. Is there any other way to get the same information from inside the Pod?

Answer (score 1):

The [`PodStatus`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/build/kubernetes/api#PodStatus) field in the [`Pod`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/build/kubernetes/api#Pod) structure has the `HostIP` field which you can use to get the IP of the node on which the pod is running.

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/vladimirvivien/k8s-client-examples/blob/master/go/podlist/maing.go) on how to get the list of pods in a namespace and iterating over them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want to get the IP of node from inside a daemonset pod. Now this node IP which I get, will be used to identify or create a different pod from inside the daemonset pod itself. So, is there a way I can get the NodeIP from already running pod without querying the name(since I might know the name of daemonset pod from inside it). The example which you have shared, suggests to list all the pods in a namespace but what I'm trying to do is get the nodeIp on which the current pod is scheduled from inside that same pod only.

Comment: You can iterate over the pods list and find the current pod and its info which has the node IP or may be I am missing something.

Comment: you can also get the specific pod using the `Get` API: `pod, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Get(pod.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})` and get the node IP from its status as described in the answer. [see example here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go#L75)